# Studying the convergence of $\int_{0}^{2}\frac{|1+\mathrm{log}x|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|\mathrm{log}x|^\beta)}\;dx$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

WolframAlpha doesn't help checking critical points. It's important for me to be sure I do this in the right way. I report my solution if someone is in the mood to read all of that. Thanks in advance to whoever helps me :)
$$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{|1+\mathrm{log}x|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|\mathrm{log}x|^\beta)}\;dx \quad \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$$
Use the following substitutions: $y=\mathrm{log}x \quad dy=\frac{dx}{x}$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\mathrm{log}2}\frac{|1+y|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|y|^\beta)}e^y \; dy$$
and also: $z=-y \quad dz=-dy$ $$\int_{+\infty}^{-\mathrm{log}2}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; (-dz)$$
swap the bounds: $$\int_{-\mathrm{log}2}^{+\infty}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz$$
The integrand has problems in $z=0$ and in $z=1$ if $\alpha < 0$, so divide the integrals in five parts:
$$\int_{-\mathrm{log}2}^{0}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \;                          + \; \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \;                                         + \; \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \;        
                                                                + \; \int_{1}^{2}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \;                                       
                                            + \; \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz$$

---

$$\int_{-\mathrm{log}2}^{0}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \; = \; \int_{0}^{\mathrm{log}2}\frac{|1+y|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|y|^\beta)}e^{y} \; dy$$
$$\text{For } \;y\to 0 \quad \frac{|1+y|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|y|^\beta)}e^{y} \; dy \; \sim \;  \frac{(1+y)^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(y^\beta)} \; \sim \; \frac{1+\alpha y -1}{y^\beta} \; \sim \; \frac{\alpha}{y^{\beta-1}} \quad \text{ so the integral converges } \iff \beta <2$$

---

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \quad \text{ leads to the same result}$$

---

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \quad \text{converges } \; \forall \alpha \geq 0 $$
$$\text{For } \; \alpha <0 \;\; z \to 1 \; \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{\frac{1}{|1-z|^{-\alpha}} -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \; \sim \; \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{\frac{1}{|1-z|^{-\alpha}} -1}{e \; \mathrm{arctan}(1)} \; dz \; \sim \; \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{\frac{1}{|1-z|^{-\alpha}}}{e \; \mathrm{arctan}(1)} \; dz \; - \; \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{1}{e 
 \; \mathrm{arctan}(1)} \; dz \; \sim \; \frac{1}{e \; \mathrm{arctan}(1)}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{1}{|1-z|^{-\alpha}} \; dz \; - \; \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{1}{e \; \mathrm{arctan}(1)} \; dz \quad \text{that converges } \iff -\alpha<1 \to \alpha > -1$$

---

$$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \quad \text{has no problems for } \alpha \geq 0, \; \text{ if } \alpha <0 \; \text{ the integrand tends to infinity for} \; z \to 1 $$

---

$$\text{For } \; z\to +\infty \; \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{|1-z|^\alpha -1}{\mathrm{arctan}(|-z|^\beta)}e^{-z} \; dz \; \sim \; \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{(z-1)^\alpha -1}{e^z \mathrm{arctan}(z^\beta)} \; dz$$
$$\text{If } \; \beta\geq 0, \; \alpha \geq 0 \; \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{(z-1)^\alpha -1}{e^z \mathrm{arctan}(z^\beta)} \; dz \; \sim \; \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{z^\alpha (1+o(1))}{e^z \mathrm{arctan}(z^\beta)} \; dz \quad \text{ that converges }$$
$$\text{If } \; \beta < 0, \; \alpha \geq 0 \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{(z-1)^\alpha -1}{e^z \mathrm{arctan}(z^\beta)} \; dz \; \sim \; \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{z^\alpha (1+o(1))-1}{e^z \frac{1}{z^\beta}} \; dz \quad \text{ that converges }$$
$$\text{If $\alpha <0$ the procedure is similar and the result is the same.}$$

---

So the starting integral converges if and only if $\alpha \in [0,+\infty) \wedge \beta \in (-\infty, 2)$.